# jQuery functionality not propagating to all areas of page

Tags: php, jquery, html

I'm using the 'timepickr' jQuery function, the problem is it works ok in the main webpage, however when I invoke it through an AJAX call, the funcionality is non-existant.  The input box is displayed fine, but the mouseover funcionality isn't there.  Code I'm using as follows....

This is the page that contains the "div2" div:  Note, the invocation of the timepickr jQuery thing works fine.

```
<head>
<link rel="Stylesheet" media="screen" href="reset.css" /> 
<link rel="Stylesheet" media="screen" href="styles.css" /> 
<link rel="Stylesheet" media="screen" href="ui.core.css" /> 
<link rel="Stylesheet" media="screen" href="ui.timepickr.css" /> 
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="jquery.timepickr.css" type="text/css" /> 
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript" SRC="js/timepicker.js"></SCRIPT> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/showDiv2Contents.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.ui.all.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.timepickr.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".timepickr").each(function(){
        $(this).timepickr();
    })
});
</script> 
</head>
<body>
<div id="div1">
<input class='timepickr' type='text' value='09:00' /><br>  <!-- This works fine -->
</div>
<select onchange="showDiv2Contents(this.value)"> 
<option value='0' selected>1</option> 
<option value='1'>2</option>
</select>
<div id="div2"></div>
</body>
```

When the dropdown box's state is changed, the showDiv2Contents js function is called, as follows:

```
function showDiv2Contents()
{
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {
        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {
        // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
            document.getElementById("div2").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","testajax2.php",true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

...and the "testajax2.php" is as follows...

```
<?php
echo "<br><br><br>";
echo "Contents of Div2:";
echo "<br><br><br>";
echo "<input class='timepickr' type='text' value='09:00'/>"; //This doesn't work
?>
```

While the contents of testajax2.php is displayed fine, the timepickr functionality is non-existant.  Any ideas?  Thanks so much in advance,

Mike

Comment: because timepickr is added onload of document and  you add elements dinamically after page load ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're already including jQuery I'd take advantage of it for the AJAX call as well, and use a `success` callback to apply the timepicker to new elements in the loaded `<div>` as well.  To do all of that, your function would be shortened down to:

```
function showDiv2Contents()
{
  $("#div2").load("testajax2.php", function() {
    $(this).find(".timepickr").timepickr();
  });
}
```

This uses [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) to get/load the ajax content of `testajax2.php` then executes the `.timepckr()` plugin again on `.timepickr` elements that were just created/loaded inside `<div id="div2">`.

Currently the dynamically loaded elements simply aren't there when the `$(".timepickr")` selector looks for results, so no code is run on them.  As an aside, your `document.ready` code can also be trimmed down, there's no need for the [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/), like this:

```
$(function() {
  $(".timepickr").timepickr();
});
```

Comment: That worked perfectly, thanks for your help, I can't vote you up because I don't have the reputation yet, but thanks for taking the time to answer my question.  Mike.

Comment: @user121136 - Welcome, be sure to accept answers (via the check-mark on the left) even if you can't vote yet :)

Answer (score 0):

try call at the end of function showDiv2Contents()

```
$('.timepickr').timepickr();
```

exactly what Nick say ....

Comment: This would re-run the plugin on *all* elements, not just the newly created ones.

Comment: yep .. it was just way, where he have to go... you write it exactly